# Display Categories in Different Layouts

Tags: component, overrides, com-content

I've got two categories, say "Cat A" and "Cat B" and both of them are associated with a menu item so that a category list can be displayed.

Now, I want to display Cat A in list style, which is the default style, and display Cat B using thumbnails as displayed below, how can I achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a "smart" layout override. The new "smart" layout can choose the right layout according the current category.

**Understanding Output Overrides**

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

**Module Layout Overrides**

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides

Following the example, you can create:

```
/templates
  /beez
    /html
      /mod_latest_news   (this directory matches the module directory name)
        default.php   ("smart" layout, loads catA or catB)
        default-catA.php   (catA layout)
        default-catB.php   (catB layout)
```

Comment: can you provide more info as i am really new to joomla

Comment: Sure, check the references